# The static method can't be acessed through an instance. Try using the class 'services' to acess the method

Tags: flutter

Hi can anyone help me with this problem I'm facing when calling API's in flutter, this is the code for fetching the data

```
class _InvestPageState extends State<InvestPage> {
  late Future<Markets> _Markets;

  @override
  void initState() {
     _Markets = Services().getMarkets(); //error here
    super.initState();
  }
```

This is the code in my API manager file

```
import 'package:gem_portal_new/Login/newsinfo.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert';

class Services {
  static const String url = 'https://ctrade.co.zw/mobileapi/MarketWatch';

  static Future<List<Markets>> getMarkets() async {
    try {
      final response = await http.get(Uri.parse(url));
      if (200 == response.statusCode) {
        final List<Markets> markets = marketsFromJson(response.body);
        return markets;
      } else {
        return <Markets>[];
      }
    } catch (e) {
      return <Markets>[]; 
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: please tell us the problem you are facing..?

Comment: Wild guess, does `Services.getMarkets();` work instead (remove the `( )`)?

Comment: I think that your api has no data..please confirm that your api have data

Comment: The static method can't be accessed through an instance.

[Docs](https://dart.dev/tools/diagnostic-messages?utm_source=dartdev&utm_medium=redir&utm_id=diagcode&utm_content=instance_access_to_static_member#instance_access_to_static_member)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to access a static method using a object instance,

Change this

```
_Markets = Services().getMarkets();
```

to

```
_Markets = Services.getMarkets();
```

Comment: Thank you this worked but I had to add 'var' in front of the text

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
  class _InvestPageState extends State<InvestPage> {
      late Future<Markets> _Markets;
    
      @override
      void initState() {
        Services().getMarkets().then((value) {
           _Markets = value;
        });
        super.initState();
      }
   }
```

You are used future return type, so you cannot be access through instance.

Comment: This didn't work it's giving me even more errors.